# Blank screen between page changes on different browsers in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, cross-browser

My ASP.NET project seems to run the best in Firefox.

Mainly while someone is navigating around the site, Firefox has no blank pages of white screen while the page is changing, and it looks like it's not reloading the top nav bar of the page or the footer/wrap around the partials that go in the middle.

Chrome and Internet Explorer (obviously) not so much. They seem to reload the entire page every time there is navigation performed.

Is there something I can change about my project configuration that would cause this kind of behaviour? I suppose it isn't too important but it would be nice if it looked as good on Chrome as it does on Firefox.

If anyone wanted to see code from a specific place/config in my ASP.NET project I can post it.

Comment: This is probably just due to browser specific behavior. If you want to ensure stuff doesn't get reloaded during navigation, you should create a [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application).

Comment: I honestly thought that was the project type I chose, I might make a new one that's definitely SPA and plug all my code in and see if that works.

Comment: @Justin - if you open the developer tools (F12), then do you see any errors in Chrome or IE that you do not see in Firefox?

Comment: It's not just about the project type, it's the whole application architecture. To be a pure SPA, there should be a single request to load a webpage to the server. After that, all calls to the server should be via AJAX (or web sockets or some other communication that doesn't cause the page to completely reload).

Comment: @KarlAnderson No I have the app error free in all 3 browsers